# How to add rows on a dataset based on a date condition?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, powerbi, powerquery

I'm having problems with a dataset I want to use to display on a PowerBI report but in some registers it has a start time and an end time with a different date, which makes me hard to display on a daily basis.

I want to divide the register automatically for each day.
I have the following register, for example:

| Date_Start | Date_End |
| --- | --- |
| 18/04/2023 10:53:00 a. m. | 20/04/2023 03:51:00 a. m. |

Since I am using `Date_Start` column to create the report on a daily basis, with this register, I can't display the date 19/04/2022, since I don't have a register on `Date_Start` with that date.
So, I want to process the register and divide it like this:

| Date_Start | Date_End |
| --- | --- |
| 18/04/2023 10:53:00 a. m. | 18/04/2023 11:59:59 p. m. |
| 19/04/2023 00:00:00 a. m. | 19/04/2023 11:59:59 p. m. |
| 20/04/2023 00:00:00 a. m. | 20/04/2023 03:51:00 a. m. |

I am not sure if this is possible using PowerQuery or maybe using Python among Pandas or Numpy library.

Can you support me with this topic?, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerquery method

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Transform({Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Date_Start]), 1)..Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From([Date_End]), 1)}, each Text.From(Date.From(_)))),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Date_Start.", each if [Index]=0 then [Custom] & " " & Text.From(DateTime.Time([Date_Start])) else [Custom] & " " &"00:00 AM"),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Date_End.", each if [Index]=List.Max(#"Added Index"[Index]) then [Custom] & " " & Text.From(DateTime.Time([Date_End])) else [Custom] & " " &"11:59 PM"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Date_Start", "Date_End", "Custom", "Index"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date_Start.", type datetime}, {"Date_End.", type datetime}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this really helped me, I just needed to change some conditions. My dataset is way larger but only with few of these cases, so "Index" condition was not working as  intended.

Answer (score 2):

With Python / [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can try this :

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

dts = [pd.date_range(s.date(), e.date(), freq="D")
       for s, e in zip(df["Date_Start"], df["Date_End"])]

starts, ends = zip(
    *[
        (
            df.iloc[i, 0] if j == 0 else ts,
            df.iloc[i, 1] if j == len(dt) - 1 else ts.replace(
                hour=23, minute=59, second=59) 
        )
        for i, dt in enumerate(dts)
        for j, ts in enumerate(dt)
    ]
)

out = (
    pd.DataFrame([[starts, ends]])
        .explode([0, 1]).explode([0, 1], ignore_index=True)
        .apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
        .str.replace("([AP])M", lambda m: f"{m.group(1).lower()}. m.", regex=True))
        .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
)
```

**NB**: In a [*12-hour clock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), there is no `00:00:00 am` but `12:00:00 am` (*start of the day*).

Output :

```
print(out)

                  Date_Start                   Date_End
0  18/04/2023 10:53:00 a. m.  18/04/2023 11:59:59 p. m.
1  19/04/2023 12:00:00 a. m.  19/04/2023 11:59:59 p. m.
2  20/04/2023 12:00:00 a. m.  20/04/2023 03:51:00 a. m.
```

*Input used :*

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Date_Start": ["18/04/2023 10:53:00 a. m."],
     "Date_End": ["20/04/2023 03:51:00 a. m."]}
)
```